# How to classify and distingush the ggplot based on two groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to subset my data in ggplot based on two Groups: `Grp1` and `Grp2`. I want to subset and represent them distinctly. How do I do it?

`dput(df)`

```
structure(list(ID = c("pathway1", "pathway2", "pathway3", "pathway4", 
"pathway5", "pathway6", "pathway7", "pathway8", "pathway9", "pathway10"
), Hit = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 9L, 6L, 4L, 13L, 6L, 16L), Zscore = c(-1.3, 
-2, 2, 3, 1, -1.3, -2, 2, 3, 1), Group = c("Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp1", 
"Grp1", "Grp1", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2", "Grp2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

I have tried following code:

```
f <- ggplot(df, aes(Zscore, ID))
f1 = f + geom_point(aes(colour = Zscore > 0, size = Hit)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = 'Z-score',
    labels = c("Suppressed", "Activated"),
    values = c(`FALSE` = 'navy', `TRUE` = 'red')
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=0, size=0.2, colour="blue", linetype="dotted") +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(0,1,2,3,5)) +
  theme(panel.background=element_rect(fill="gray95", colour="gray95"),
        panel.grid.major=element_line(size=0.1,linetype='solid', colour="gray90"), 
        panel.grid.minor=element_line(size=0.1,linetype='solid', colour="gray90"),
        axis.title.y=element_blank()) +
  expand_limits(x=c(-3,3)) +
  # scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3, 4, 5, 6)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Z-score', breaks = pretty(data$Zscore)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits=rev(df$ID)) + theme(axis.text = element_text(face="bold"))
f1
```

It resulted in:
[image: output]

pathway1 to pathway5 are from `Grp1` and remaining are from `Grp2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
f <- ggplot(data = df, aes(Zscore, ID, color = Group)) 
f1 <- f + geom_point(aes(size = Hit)) +
  scale_color_manual(
    name = 'Group',
    values = c("Grp1" = 'red', "Grp2" = 'blue')
  ) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, size = 0.2, colour = "blue", linetype = "dotted") +
  scale_size_continuous(breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 5)) +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = "gray95", colour = "gray95"),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray90"), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', colour = "gray90"),
        axis.title.y = element_blank()) +
  expand_limits(x = c(-3, 3)) +
  scale_x_continuous(name = 'Z-score', breaks = pretty(df$Zscore)) +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev(df$ID)) + theme(axis.text = element_text(face = "bold"))

f1
```